# Whats the difference between request_spot_instances and create_instances with InstanceMarketOptions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Why is there `request_spot_instances` when it seems like you can do the same thing with `create_instances` by specifying `InstanceMarketOptions`? (In the AWS API that's RequestSpotInstances vs RunInstances)

Followup: How do you get the spot request id from `create_instances`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are very simillar, but [RunInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RunInstances.html#API_RunInstances_Examples) can create spot request only for a **single instance type**. For example, `t2.micro`.

[RequestSpotInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RequestSpotInstances.html) is much more general and versatile. This is because you can make spot request for a [fleet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet.html) of instances. This means that your one spot request can contain **numerous instance types**, e.g. `t2.micro`, `m4.medium`, `t3.large`, or even more general that this, like create any instance type which has `1GB<RAM<10GB` and `2<CPU<16`.